# nodejs socket.io clients not exchange emitted messages

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i have a strange behaviour with nodejs and socket.io
On the node server socket.io works well :

```
...
const nodeServer = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(
        '%s App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode',
        chalk.green('✓'),
        app.get('port'),
        app.get('env')
    );

});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(nodeServer);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('new_message', function(msg){
        console.log('emit message: ' + msg.message);
        socket.emit('new_message', msg);
    });
});
```

On client side, i have a simple call to emit and receive data :

```
<script src="socket.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    const chat = io.connect('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4000');

  // ..... Send message
  document.getElementById('sendChat').addEventListener('click', function(event){
     chat.emit('new_message', {message: document.getElementById('message').value});
  })

  // ..... Receive message
  chat.on('new_message', (data) => {
     console.log(data.message)
     $('.chatRoom').append('<p class="message">'+data.message+'</p>');
  })
</script>
```

**NOW I WILL OPEN 2 CLIENTS :**

With this script, i should have a console printed and the message appended to a div when received message with "new_message" event.
When i send message from first client, the second client doesn't receive message, and vis-versa, **BUT the message is showing on the .chatRoom div of current client, so i consider the server received and emit the message well.**

**The node js server output both messages from client1 and client2**

Someone has an explanation on this?

Thank you.

Comment: On the server, replace `socket.emit` with `io.emit`.

Answer (score 0):

It's how `socket.emit` works, it sends back a message to the sender (current client).

To send to all clients, use (server side):

```
io.emit('message', "this is a test");
```

With your code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(nodeServer);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('new_message', function(msg){
        console.log('emit message: ' + msg.message);
        io.emit('new_message', msg);
    });
});
```

Check the [Socket.IO cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#), the docs of [rooms and namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#) could be useful too.

I hope it helps!